# React state return array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please help me,

I want get data from api with axios and result return listview, but i get an error, it doesn't seem to return array

```
import React, { lazy, Component } from "react";
state = { data: [] }
class ProductListView extends Component {
getProducts = () => {
    this.setState({ data: [{'obj': 'value'}] });<br/>
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return this.state.data;
  };

}
export default ProductListView;

result return console.log:
  Array [ { obj: "value" } ] 
  function products.slice is ok
​
but when i get api
...

getProducts = () => {
    let res = UserService.getAll().then(response => response.data);
    this.setState({ data: res });
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return this.state.data;
  };
...

result return console.log:

Promise { <state>: "pending" }
​
<state>: "fulfilled"
​
<value>: Array(18) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]

TypeError: products.slice is not a function
```

Hope to get an answer , tks

Comment: Please make sure to have state inside of class. Here state is being placed out of class as a result `this.state` couldn't point to expected location

Comment: Is it possible to attach the entire code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `async/await` in this case:

```
getProducts = async () => {
  let res = await UserService.getAll();
  console.log(res.data);
  this.setState({ data: res.data });
};
```

Comment: Thanks,  but return console.log empty and  TypeError: products.slice is not a function
```
getProducts = async () => {
    let res = await UserService.getAll();
    this.setState({ data: res.data });
    const products = this.state.data;
    console.log(products);
    return products;
  };
```